# How can I use "import" in my ASP.NET MVC ReactJS project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4, reactjs.net

Being new to both ReactJS and ASP.NET MVC, I am having trouble using the `import` key word for including my `anyComponent.jsx` files.

I have only figured out **two** options:

1. Use a script tag on the `index.cshtml` page
2. Leave all components in one file

In my other projects, I have used Webpack and Babel but understand very little of how they work so I assume that ASP.NET MVC has it's own bundling that I understand even less.

The Nuget packages installed are:

- React.Core
- React.Web
- React.Web.Mvc4

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReactJS.NET doesn't support JavaScript modules. You'll need to use a browser build (eg. via Webpack or Browserify).